# unique constraint violation on a row causes entire pq.CopyIn postgresql import to fail

Tags: sql, go, postgresql-9.5

I'm trying to use pq.CopyIn to do bulk imports as described here:

https://godoc.org/github.com/lib/pq

The import is much faster than other methods I've tried but I am finding that a unique constraint violation in just one record will cause the entire import to fail.

Is there any way to set ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING using pq.CopyIn.

Here is a copy of my table structure

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    unique_token VARCHAR ( 10 ) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    frequency INT DEFAULT 0
);
```

I tried using @mkopriva answer below but I'm getting Error: pq: null
value in column "id" violates not-null constraint

Code sample below

```
tx, _ := db.Begin()

_, err = tx.Exec(`CREATE TEMP TABLE token_temp ON COMMIT DROP AS 
   SELECT id, unique_token FROM test WITH NO DATA`)
if err != nil {
    return err
}

stmt, err := tx.Prepare(pq.CopyIn("token_temp", "unique_token"))
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("error here")
    return err
}

for _, token := range tokenList {
    _, err = stmt.Exec(token)

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

}

_, err = stmt.Exec()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

err = stmt.Close()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

_, err = tx.Exec(`INSERT INTO test SELECT id, unique_token FROM 
  token_temp   ON CONFLICT(unique_token) DO UPDATE SET frequency= 
   test.frequency + 1 `)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error")
    return err
}

err = tx.Commit()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pq.CopyIn` internally uses [`COPY FROM`](https://postgresql.org/docs/13/interactive/sql-copy.html) which has no support for the `ON CONFLICT` clause.

What you can do, however, is to create a temporary table that has no constraints, copy the data into that temporary table, and then do an `INSERT` into the target table, with your `ON CONFLICT` clause, using the temporary table as the source of the data to be inserted.

An example should make this more clear, say you have a `users` table that looks like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE users (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY
    , name text
    , email text UNIQUE
);
```

And say you have a slice of users like this:

```golang
var users = []User{
    {Name: "John Doe", Email: "jdoe@example.com"},
    {Name: "Joe Blow", Email: "jblow@example.com"},
    {Name: "Jane Doe", Email: "jdoe@example.com"}, // duplicate email!
    {Name: "Foo Bar", Email: "fbar@example.com"},
}
```

With that you can do the following:

```golang
_, err = txn.Exec(`
CREATE TEMP TABLE users_temp
ON COMMIT DROP
AS SELECT * FROM users
WITH NO DATA`)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

stmt, err := txn.Prepare(pq.CopyIn("users_temp", "name", "email"))
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

for _, u := range users {
    if _, err := stmt.Exec(u.Name, u.Email); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
if _, err := stmt.Exec(); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
if err := stmt.Close(); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

_, err = txn.Exec(`
INSERT INTO users (name, email)
SELECT name, email FROM users_temp
ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING`)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

if err := txn.Commit(); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

After you run the above you can do `SELECT * FROM users;` and you'll get this:

```
 id |   name   |       email
----+----------+-------------------
  1 | John Doe | jdoe@example.com
  2 | Joe Blow | jblow@example.com
  4 | Foo Bar  | fbar@example.com
(3 rows)
```

---

For you specific example and requirement you can do something like this in the `INSERT ... SELECT ...` query:

```golang
_, err = txn.Exec(`
INSERT INTO test (unique_token, frequency)
SELECT unique_token, COUNT(*) FROM token_temp
GROUP BY unique_token`)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Comment: I tried this but I'm getting Error: pq: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint

Comment: @rossi Well how to exactly do the `INSERT ... SELECT ...` will depend on the structure of your table. You haven't provided that so I can't answer with a precise code snippet for your case. All I can give you is an example that you should use *as* an example, not as literal solution.

Comment: @rossi `serial` is syntax sugar for `CREATE SEQUENCE` and then that's used as the `DEFAULT` for the column (in this case `id`). Stuff like `DEFAULT` and `CONSTRAINTS` don't get added to the temp table. So what you need to do is to leave the `serial` functionality to the target table, i.e. `INSERT INTO test (unique_token) SELECT unique_token FROM ...`.

Comment: @rossi I've updated my answer to reflect the id requirement. I've also executed it on my machine and it works.

Comment: It's worked.  I'm trying to insert about 10,000,000 rows into my table and when there is a  duplicate row,  update the frequency by 1 but still got pq: ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE command cannot affect row a second time

Comment: Part of the requirements is store a token(which is gotten from an external source) in the db and I want to ensure these aren't duplicated in the DB, so when there is an on conflict error update the frequency by 1

Comment: @rossi I've added an update specific to your case and requirement, see if that helps.

Comment: @rossi note that the solution provided will produce `frequence = 1` for `unique_tokens` that did not have a duplicate, and `frequency = 2` for `unique_toknes` that has one duplicate. If you need them to be `0` for no duplicate and `1` for one duplicate you can simply change the select to use `COUNT(*) - 1`

Comment: Thanks. It worked.. Too an average of 14m14.1808822s to successfully execute